# Derivative Symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to create derivative symbol. How can I make the derivative symbol here?

[image]

Comment: have you tried `$f'(1)$`?

Comment: `f'` it just looks straight as you are using a sans serif font, I think

Comment: Yes i tried. I want the line to appear straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also work with a `\rule` here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath

\newcommand{\straightsinglequote}{\hspace{0.3ex}\rule[0.2ex]{0.17ex}{1ex}}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm f^{\straightsinglequote}(1)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The upquote package will give you what you want.  Here are four variants.  My own preference is for the first two, but it seems you want one or the other of the last two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}
    
\[
f(x) = x^2 \quad  f'(x) = 2x
\]
    
\[
f(x) = x^2 \quad  f^\prime(x) = 2x
\]

\[
f(x) = x^2 \quad  f^{\verb!'!}(x) = 2x
\]

\[
f(x) = x^2 \quad  f^\text{\textquotesingle}(x) = 2x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\[
f(x) = x^2 \quad  f'(x) = 2x
\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. I want the line to be straight. @Edson Marcon